# How do i checkout a single folder / file from a remote repo using github actions

Tags: git, github, repository, github-actions, git-checkout

I'm using github actions runner on windows.

I tried the below to checkout only the `scripts` folder from remote repo called `betech` from branch `mm365` inside the `current-folder\betech`; but it checks out the entire repo contents.

```
  - name: Checkout just the scripts folder
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      repository: mytech/betech
      ref: mm365
      path: betech
      token: ${{ secrets.MYGITHUBTOKEN }}

  - name: Configure Sparse Checkout   
    run: |
      echo "scripts/*" >> .git/info.sparse-checkout
      git read-tree -mu HEAD
    working-directory: betech

    env:
      token: ${{ secrets.MYGITHUBTOKEN }}
      secrets: inherit
```

here is the sparse file

```
cat betech\.git\info.sparse-checkout

scripts/*
```

Can you please suggest how I can checkout only the scripts folder or any single file [If the logic is comparatively different]

*** Update: ***
I tied the below answer and it works.

```
  - name: Checkout just the scripts folder
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      repository: mytech/betech
      ref: mm365
      path: betech
      sparse-checkout: |
        scripts
      sparse-checkout-cone-mode: false
      token: ${{ secrets.MYGITHUBTOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`checkout` action documentation](https://github.com/actions/checkout#scenarios) have few examples demonstrating how to fetch specific files.

> [Fetch only the root files](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-only-the-root-files)
>
> ```
> - uses: actions/checkout@v3   
>   with:
>     sparse-checkout: .
> ```
>
> [Fetch only the root files and .github and src folder](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-only-the-root-files-and-github-and-src-folder)
>
> ```
> - uses: actions/checkout@v3
>   with:
>     sparse-checkout: |
>       .github
>       src
> ```
>
> [Fetch only a single file](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-only-a-single-file)
>
> ```
> - uses: actions/checkout@v3
>   with:
>     sparse-checkout: |
>       README.md
>     sparse-checkout-cone-mode: false
> ```

You can also use [`checkout-files` action](https://github.com/Bhacaz/checkout-files#checkout-files) to checkout only certain files and/or folders. This action uses [Github REST API to download the repository content](https://github.com/Bhacaz/checkout-files/blob/master/index.js#L22-L28).

```
- name: Checkout files
  uses: Bhacaz/checkout-files@v2
  with:
   files: package.json
```

Here the [`files` is a list of files with the path separated by a space, relative to root of your repository. This can also be a folder and the action will recursively pull all the files.](https://github.com/Bhacaz/checkout-files#inputs)

Comment: Just in case anyone has problems, the paths should not be in double quotes!